# Follow up to a question, why does proof $\rho(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ work

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, solution-verification

This is a follow up to a well known question

[Showing $\rho (x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686792/showing-rho-x-y-fracdx-y1dx-y-is-a-metric)

A general proof is as follows: Let $x,y,z \in (X, \rho)$

\begin{align}
\rho(x,z) &= \dfrac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}\\ & \leq  \dfrac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}\\ &=  \dfrac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} +  \dfrac{d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} \\&\leq \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)
\end{align}

This might be very simple but how do you rigorously argue that

> $$\dfrac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}\leq 
>  \dfrac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$$

If only the numerator guy got bigger due to triangle inequality, then I would have no problem. However, the thing in the denominator also got bigger. How do we know that this inequality holds?

Comment: Cross multiply then use the triangle inequality

Comment: I'd say $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$ : $f(a) \le f(b) + f(c)$ whenever $a \le b+c$

Comment: Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$. We have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}>0$, so f is strictly increasing and preserves inequality. Therefore $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ implies inequality $f(d(x,z))\leq f(d(x,y)+d(y,z))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 \le a < b \implies 0 \le \frac{a}{b} \le\frac{a+n}{b+n}< 1$ where $n\ge0$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a+n}{b+n}=1$

We can use this since, of course, the difference between the numerators is the same as the difference between the denominators.

see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/effect-of-adding-a-constant-to-both-numerator-and-denominator) if you want a proof of the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

One general reason, as user1952009 notes in the comments, is that $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + x}$ is [increasing and concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707468/is-this-a-metric-on-r/707533#707533) on $[0, \infty)$.