# When does a $c$ exist such that $(a/b)^{\delta} < (a+1/b+1)^{\delta + c}$.

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

Let $a>b > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$, then does there exist a $c$ such that
\begin{align*}
 \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{\delta} & \leq  \left( \dfrac{a+1}{b+1} \right)^{\delta + c}\\
\end{align*}

Of course if $c = 0$, we get the opposite inequality due to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/effect-of-adding-a-constant-to-both-numerator-and-denominator)
$$ \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{\delta} >  \left( \dfrac{a+1}{b+1} \right)^{\delta } \,. $$

It also seems that $c$ must be more than or equal to 1, but is there a generic construction of $c$?

Comment: Playing with logarithm and the fact that $\ln(x+1) = \ln(x) + \ln(1+1/x)$ we can get :
$$
\begin{align}
\delta(\ln a - \ln b) \leq (\delta + c) (\ln(a) + \ln(1+1/a) - \ln(b) - \ln(1+1/b) ) \Leftrightarrow \\
0 \leq \delta(\ln(1+1/a) - \ln(1+1/b)) + c( \ln(a+1) - \ln(b+1) ) \Leftrightarrow \\
-\frac{\delta(\ln(1+1/a) - \ln(1+1/b))}{ \ln(a+1) - \ln(b+1) } \leq c
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Zubzub. That's helpful, but I would like $c$ to be independent of $b$. I know this might not be possible without knowing more about $b$, but I was curious if the community had any ideas.